# Why does my model work with `tf.GradientTape()` but fail when using `keras.models.Model.fit()`

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

After much effort, I managed to build a `tensorflow 2` implementation of an existing `pytorch` style-transfer project. Then I wanted to get all the nice extra features that are available through Keras standard learning, e.g. `model.fit()`.

But the same model fails when learning through `model.fit()`. The model seems to learn the content features, but is unable to learn style features. This is the diagram of the model in quesion:

[image]

```
def vgg_layers19(content_layers, style_layers, input_shape=(256,256,3)):
  """ creates a VGG model that returns output values for the given layers
  see: https://keras.io/applications/#extract-features-from-an-arbitrary-intermediate-layer-with-vgg19
  Returns: 
    function(x, preprocess=True):
      Args: 
        x: image tuple/ndarray h,w,c(RGB), domain=(0.,255.)
      Returns:
        a tuple of lists, ([content_features], [style_features])
  usage:
    (content_features, style_features) = vgg_layers16(content_layers, style_layers)(x_train)
  """
  preprocessingFn = tf.keras.applications.vgg19.preprocess_input
  base_model = tf.keras.applications.VGG19(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=input_shape)
  base_model.trainable = False
  content_features = [base_model.get_layer(name).output for name in content_layers]
  style_features = [base_model.get_layer(name).output for name in style_layers]
  output_features = content_features + style_features

  model = Model( inputs=base_model.input, outputs=output_features, name="vgg_layers")
  model.trainable = False

  def _get_features(x, preprocess=True):
    """
    Args:
      x: expecting tensor, domain=255. hwcRGB
    """
    if preprocess and callable(preprocessingFn): 
      x = preprocessingFn(x)
    output = model(x) # call as tf.keras.Layer()
    return ( output[:len(content_layers)], output[len(content_layers):] )

  return _get_features 



class VGG_Features():
""" get content and style features from VGG model """
  def __init__(self, loss_model, style_image=None, target_style_gram=None):
    self.loss_model = loss_model
    if style_image is not None:
      assert style_image.shape == (256,256,3), "ERROR: loss_model expecting input_shape=(256,256,3), got {}".format(style_image.shape)
      self.style_image = style_image
      self.target_style_gram = VGG_Features.get_style_gram(self.loss_model, self.style_image)
    if target_style_gram is not None:
      self.target_style_gram = target_style_gram

  @staticmethod
  def get_style_gram(vgg_features_model, style_image):
    style_batch = tf.repeat( style_image[tf.newaxis,...], repeats=_batch_size, axis=0)
    # show([style_image], w=128, domain=(0.,255.) )

    # B, H, W, C = style_batch.shape
    (_, style_features) = vgg_features_model( style_batch , preprocess=True ) # hwcRGB
    target_style_gram = [ fnstf_utils.gram(value)  for value in style_features ]  # list
    return target_style_gram  

  def __call__(self, input_batch):
    content_features, style_features = self.loss_model( input_batch, preprocess=True )
    style_gram = tuple(fnstf_utils.gram(value)  for value in style_features)  # tuple(<generator>)
    return (content_features[0],) + style_gram  # tuple = tuple + tuple




class TransformerNetwork_VGG(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, transformer=transformer, vgg_features=vgg_features):
    super(TransformerNetwork_VGG, self).__init__()
    self.transformer = transformer 
    # type: tf.keras.models.Model
    # input_shapes:  (None, 256,256,3)
    # output_shapes: (None, 256,256,3)


    style_model = {
       'content_layers':['block5_conv2'],
       'style_layers': ['block1_conv1',
                  'block2_conv1',
                  'block3_conv1', 
                  'block4_conv1', 
                  'block5_conv1']
    }
    vgg_model = vgg_layers19( style_model['content_layers'], style_model['style_layers'] )

    self.vgg_features = VGG_Features(vgg_model, style_image=style_image, batch_size=batch_size) 

    # input_shapes:  (None, 256,256,3)
    # output_shapes: [(None, 16, 16, 512),  (None, 64, 64), (None, 128, 128), (None, 256, 256), (None, 512, 512), (None, 512, 512)]
    #                [ content_loss,        style_loss_1, style_loss_2, style_loss_3, style_loss_4, style_loss_5 ]


  def call(self, inputs):
    x = inputs                # shape=(None, 256,256,3)

    # shape=(None, 256,256,3)
    generated_image = self.transformer(x)                    

    # shape=[(None, 16, 16, 512),  (None, 64, 64), (None, 128, 128), (None, 256, 256), (None, 512, 512), (None, 512, 512)]
    vgg_feature_losses = self.vgg(generated_image)           

    return vgg_feature_losses       # tuple(content1, style1, style2, style3, style4, style5)
```

Style Image
[image: style image]

FEATURE_WEIGHTS= [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]

### `GradientTape` learning

With the `tf.GradientTape()` loop, I'm manually handling the multiple outputs, e.g. tuple of 6 tensors, from `TransformerNetwork_VGG(x_train)`. This method learns correctly.

```
  @tf.function()
  def train_step(x_train, y_true, loss_weights=None, log_freq=10):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
      y_pred = TransformerNetwork_VGG(x_train)
      generated_content_features = y_pred[:1]
      generated_style_gram = y_pred[1:]


      y_true = TransformerNetwork_VGG.vgg(x_train)
      target_content_features = y_true[:1]
      target_style_gram = TransformerNetwork_VGG.vgg.target_style_gram

      content_loss = get_MEAN_mse_loss(target_content_features, generated_content_features, weights)
      style_loss = tuple(get_MEAN_mse_loss(x,y)*w for x,y,w in zip(target_style_gram, generated_style_gram, weights))

      total_loss = content_loss + = tf.reduce_sum(style_loss)
      TransformerNetwork = TransformerNetwork_VGG.transformer
      grads = tape.gradient(total_loss, TransformerNetwork.trainable_weights)
      optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, TransformerNetwork.trainable_weights))
```

```
# GradientTape epoch=5: 
# losses:             [   6078.71         70.23  4495.13 13817.65 88217.99    48.36]
```

[image: gradient tape]

### `model.fit()` learning

With `tf.keras.models.Model.fit()`, the multiple outputs, e.g. tuple of 6 tensors, are fed to the loss function individually as `loss(y_pred, y_true)` and then multipled by the correct weight on `reduction`. This method does learn to approximate the content_image, but **does not learn** to minimize the style losses! II cannot figure out why.

```
  history = TransformerNetwork_VGG.fit(
    x=train_dataset.repeat(NUM_EPOCHS),
    epochs=NUM_EPOCHS,
    steps_per_epoch=NUM_BATCHES,
    callbacks=callbacks,
  )
```

```
# model.fit() epoch=5: 
# losses:             [  4661.08       219.95   6959.01   4897.39 209201.16     84.68]]
```

[image: model-fit]

> 50 epochs, with boosted style_weights, 
>   FEATURE_WEIGHTS= [   0.1854,           1605.23,   25.08,    8.16,    1.28, 2330.79]  # boost style loss x100

[image: model-fit after 50]

> step=50, losses=[269899.45    337.5   69617.7   38424.96   9192.36  85903.44  66423.51]

### check `mse` losses * weights

I tested my model with losses and weights fixed as follows
* FEATURE_WEIGHTS = SEQ = [1.,2.,3.,4.,5.,6.,]
* MSELoss(y_true, y_pred) == tf.ones() of equal shape 
and confirmed that `model.fit()` is handling multiple output losses * weights correctly

[image: losses as ones]

I've checked everything I can think of, but I cannot figure out how to make the model learn correctly with `model.fit()`. What am I missing??

The full notebook is available here: https://colab.research.google.com/github/mixuala/fast_neural_style_pytorch/blob/master/notebook/%5BSO%5D_FastStyleTransfer.ipynb

Comment: Can you please provide the definitiojn for `TransformerNetwork_VGG.vgg()`?

Comment: But from first impression, `model.fit` and `GradientTape` are attempting to fit two different models. `model.fit` trains `TransformerNetwork_VGG`, while `GradientTape` trains `TransformerNetwork_VGG.transformer`.

Comment: I seemed to have broken things when I "refactored" the code for stackoverflow and now nothing learns correctly. Still trying to earlier revisions to see what worked.  But I'll add the most recent code for  `TransformerNetwork_VGG` to the question

Comment: But the original idea of `TransformerNetwork_VGG` was to set `TransformerNetwork_VGG.vgg.loss_model.trainable=False` to fix the VGG19 weights. Otherwise, with `model.fit()` I was having problems handling both the loss from the multiple outputs of VGG_Features() and the `content_loss` from the generated image after the transformer. the `model.fit()` loss function only takes `(y_true,y_pred)` as args.

Comment: this stuff stinks. I "cleaned" up my notebook before I posted this question, only to discover that it no longer worked even with `tf.GradientTape`.  I spent a week building unit tests for every piece of code. Finally, after carefully comparing loss values between an old notebook and the current one (MANUALLY), I discovered that my `target_style_gram` was calculated using a style_image with `domain=(0,1)` but my input images were fed with `domain=(0,255)`. doh!!!  it now works.

Comment: We've all had our share of experiences with value ranges :). Glad you figured it out.

Comment: haha, thanks for your empathy. But all this means is that I can ask the question I was originally gonna ask--why does my model mysteriously FAIL after about 3700 batches? Thats gonna be another question...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60630859/why-did-my-style-transfer-model-suddenly-stop-learning-after-3700-20000-batches